# At what level for a 4/5-player party would a CR 2-3 monster be considered a "miniboss"?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, encounter-design, cr-calculation

I'm working on a dungeon and I want to have a solo encounter with a single basilisk in the hallway. It isn't the last monster in the dungeon; that I'm going with a surprise, however it shouldn't be a quick fight either. I have a few CR 1/4 trash mobs in the first half followed by some clever traps.

About when would you suggest I spring this on my players?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Two, Three, or Never

A Basilisk (CR3) is worth 700xp.

Checking [Kobold Fight Club](https://koboldplus.club/), I see that 700xp is a "deadly" encounter for a group of five level-1 PCs.  It's a "hard" encounter for a group of five level-two PCs, or a "medium" encounter for a group of five level-three PCs.

Please think carefully before using this monster in your dungeon, because it has a chance of causing (essentially) PC death to any character who sees it.  If PC death would be bad for your game, you shouldn't use a monster that is likely to cause it.  (Or see [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/192255/petrification-at-low-levels/192257#192257) discussion about petrification for low-level parties.)

Comment: My answer [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/192257/62294) gives some pretty detailed guidance about implementing petrification at lower levels.